# Umbraco AJAX partial view controller action call - unable to retrieve the Umbraco.Context

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the following scenario: *Calendar* page that loads the initial sale nodes from last 2 months. This page has a *Load more* button that fetches more *Sale* items that are 2 additional months of *Sales*.

I have added the call to the to controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult LoadMoreSales(int months = 0)
{
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["department"] == null)
            {
                return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales", GetSales(0, months));
            }
            else
            {
                int depId = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["department"], out depId);

                return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales", GetSales(depId, months));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales");
        }
}
```

*GetSale* retrieves the list of *SaleViewModel* and the *_Sales* partial is used when accessing the *Calendar* page and when clicking *Load more* button. Through this method, the AJAX call is being made and the list is being retrieved.

The *_Sales* partial inherits the following:

`@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IEnumerable<SaleViewModel>>`

The click button jQuery event:

```
$('.js-reload-details').on('click', function (evt) {
    $('div#loading').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var $detailsDiv = $('#detailsDiv'),
        url = $(this).data('url');

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $detailsDiv.replaceWith(data);
    });

    $('div#loading').empty();
});
```

And the button click is implemented like this:

```
<a id="loadMore" class="js-reload-details cta" data-url="@Url.Action("LoadMoreSales", "Calendar", new { months = -2})" href="javascript:;">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Calendar.LoadMore")</a>
```

The *Sale* items are being loaded, but I am unable to access *UmbracoHelper* and when I add macros to the list of sales page field, the call breaks since there is no *UmbracoContext* reference. Also, the following dictionary calls don't work:

`@umbracoHelper.GetDictionaryValue("Calendar.ViewDetails")`

Did anyone have the similar issue?

[Related our.umbraco forum post](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7//73086-umbraco-ajax-partial-view-controller-action-call-unable-to-retrieve-the-umbracocontext)

**EDIT**

I have also tried the following submit form implementation, but the result is the same:

AJAX form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadMoreSales", 
                       "Calendar",  
                       new {months = -2}, 
                       new AjaxOption { HttpMethod = "GET", 
                                        OnSuccess = "loadMore(data, status, xhr)" }))
```

jQuery implementation:

```
function loadMore(data, status, xhr) {
        $('div#loading').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');

        if (data != '') {
            $("#saleList").append(data);
        }

        $('div#loading').empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:  Added fixed implementation.

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the `CultureInfo` before returning the `PartialView` like so: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture)`

The action method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult LoadMoreSales(int months = 0, string culture = "")
{
        // Set the 'CultureInfo' to perserve 'UmbracoContext' when performing an AJAX call
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["department"] == null)
            {
                return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales", GetSales(0, months));
            }
            else
            {
                int depId = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["department"], out depId);

                return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales", GetSales(depId, months));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("Calendar/_Sales");
        }
}
```

I have added the hidden `cultureInfo` tag in the `.cshtml`:

```
<div id="cultureInfo" hidden>@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture</div>
```

The jQuery was also modified to read and pass the hidden value to the controllers action like so:

```
        var cultureInfo = $('#cultureInfo').html();

        $.get("/umbraco/surface/Calendar/LoadMoreSales?months=" + months + "&culture=" + cultureInfo, function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                $("#saleList").append(data);
            }
            else {
                months = -1;
                $("#saleList").append('No more news to display');
            }

            _inCallback = false;
            $('div#loading').empty();
        });
```

There was no need to change `.cshtml` file, the dictionary values are being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Marko,

This was in v6 but similar issue, so in the partial i did

var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
Regards

Ismail

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ismail. I have just tried that and the *umbracoHelper* properties either throw an exception or they are null. Is there something else I have to modify to ensure the correct context is loaded?

Comment: I have also tried the AJAX implementation, but without success - see the post edit at the bottom.

Comment: Ismail, I have been able to resolve the issue by using `CultureInfo`. Take a look at my answer for this question.