# Culture for Umbraco API Controller

Tags: umbraco, cultureinfo, umbraco7

I can change the language for an Umbraco Surface Controller but I cannot see how to change it for an Umbraco API controller.

Even though I can change the culture in my global.ascx BeginRequest the Model is still trying to bind a date using en-US rather than en-UK.

I have also tried custom model binding but that does not seem to fire at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `CurrentUICulture`, in you API Controller? Like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825225/umbraco-ajax-partial-view-controller-action-call-unable-to-retrieve-the-umbrac) when trying to retrieve `Umbraco.Context` in regular Umbraco Controller.